# How to merge two arrays by ID in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, merge, collections, mutablelist

I have two arrays like:

```
val array1 = arrayOf(
  arrayOf("001", "Product name", "Product group"),
  arrayOf("002", "Product name", "Product group"),
  arrayOf("003", "Product name", "Product group"),
  arrayOf("004", "Product name", "Product group"),
  arrayOf("005", "Product name", "Product group")
)

val array2 = arrayOf(
  arrayOf("001", "Property1"),
  arrayOf("002", "Property2"),
  arrayOf("004", "Property4")
)
```

How can I merge both arrays in one by use of the ID (first column)? The result table (array or mutablelist) should contain ALL columns from `array1` and only match results from `array2` from second column. It should look like following structure:

```
val array3 = arrayOf(
  arrayOf("001", "Product name", "Product group", "Property1"),
  arrayOf("002", "Product name", "Product group", "Property2"),
  arrayOf("003", "Product name", "Product group", "NO MATCH"),
  arrayOf("004", "Product name", "Product group", "Property4"),
  arrayOf("005", "Product name", "Product group", "NO MATCH")
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we need to create a lookup map for the second list, so we can easily search for the property by its ID. Then we can use it when transforming the first list:

```kotlin
val prop2ById = array2.associate { it[0] to it[1] }
val array3 = array1.map { it + arrayOf(prop2ById.getOrDefault(it[0], "NO MATCH")) }
```

I assume the ID in the second array is unique.

Also, it seems you represent objects as arrays. If each column is meaningful, it means a very specific piece of data, we should not represent this as an array, but as an object or optionally a map. Using arrays here is much more error-prone and bad for the code quality in general.

Comment: Hello broot, thank you for your reply. I redesigned the code based on provided by you information: [link](https://pl.kotl.in/6YBHRPQ0f?theme=darcula)

Unfortunatelly it does not work due to the mismatch of the data type. I tried different types like Map, List, Array etc. - nothing is working. What is wrong?

Comment: That `it + arrayOf` is there only because in your original example data was stored in arrays, so we could add another column by simply joining two arrays. If we use data classes, then we need another class to store all 4 columns and then we have to use it: https://pl.kotl.in/4lbAJ5ZZH Or we can reuse `Array1Data` by adding a nullable property to it, but in most cases I personally prefer separate classes, even if that requires additional code.